# DataGridView сортировка в заданном промежутке

Tags: c#, datagridview

Привет, не могу понять как сделать фильтрацию в промежутке: имеются 2 textBox'а, в них выставляется максимальное и минимальное значение (цена) и по нажатию на кнопку в таблице остаются строчки с этим промежутком.

Comment: Приведите пример, что записано в таблице

Comment: Это WinForms? Как данные попадают в грид: напрямую или через привязку (binding)? Где данные хранятся: в `DataTable`, типизированной коллекции или как-то ещё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать, используя свойство строки `bool DataGridView.Rows[i].Visible`. В обработчике `OnClick` кнопки пишете:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[n] == null || row.Cells[n].Value == null)
            break;

        int price;

        if (int.TryParse(row.Cells[n].Value.ToString(), out price) )
            if (price > Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMaxValue.Text) || 
                price < Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMinValue.Text))
            {
                row.Visible = false;
            }        
    }
}
```

где `n` - номер столбца "Цена".

Сюда стоит еще добавить проверку на введенные в `textBox'ы` значения, но это не относится к сути вопроса. Я думаю, автор при необходимости сам сможет сделать все необходимые проверки.